# Specifying # of Posts per page using inline post plugin (:

Tags: posts, pages

I am working on a website for my school.
I downloaded the inline post plugin. This plug-in allows you to make posts on multiple pages throughout the site. However, I am having trouble displaying a certain number of posts per page.

Please let me know what I can do.
Thank you (:

Answer (score 2):

According to the plugin's description in order to embed a post, you need to enter the post ID in the square brackets.

For example `[42]` will embed the post with ID 42.

So I assume to include multiple posts you have to include multiple IDs using the same short code.

Example `[22][37][42]`

P.S - Didnt test it.